# How to decrypt the encrypted UID using firestore security rules?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

1. I get the `uid`, when **users** login to firebase for the first time
   using `phone number`.
2. Then I have encrypted the `uid`.
3. Then I have created a **Collection** as `users` with **Document Id** `uid` in the firestore like: `users/uid`.
4. Now the users want to write into `users/userId`, if the
   `condition` is `true` like below:

```
  match /users/{userId} {
     allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
  }
```

Here as I mentioned in `number 2` the `userId` is encrypted, but the `request.auth.uid` is not encrypted.

So how we can decrypt it here the `(userId)` ?

If I use hashing sha256, so how can I decode the sha256 in client side ?

*I am using `crypto-js`*

Comment: I dont know why people are voting down, instead of some their kind directions

Comment: You might want to edit your question to show more details about what you're trying to accomplish, including any existing code you have.

Comment: I have edited you now can see the edited question

Answer (score 8):

According to the documentation, you can [use hashed values in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.hashing).  If you are not using one of the hashing algorithms described, then it will not work.  You can read about how it works in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#how-can-you-use-it_3):

> New hashing and hashing-adjacent methods are:
>
> ```
> hashing.crc32()
> hashing.crc32c()
> hashing.sha256()
> hashing.md5()
> <ByteValue>.toBase64()
> <ByteValue>.toHexString()
> <String>.toUtf8()
> ```
>
> For example, previously, if the version of an email in Firestore was
>   hashed with SHA-256, you wouldn't be able to compare that email to the
>   plaintext email sent with the auth object. Now you can:
>
> ```
> hashing.sha256(request.auth.email.utf8()) == resource.data.ownerEmailHash
> ```
>
> Alternatively, if you have a field in a document for users to store
>   their novellas, you may want to have a shorter identifier for that
>   very long string:
>
> ```
> match /novellas/{hash} {
>  allow write: if hash == hashing.sha256(request.resource.data.
>            novella.utf8()) && resource == null
> }
> ```
>
> Strings are treated as UTF-8-encoded bytes, and the return value is a
>   Bytes type:
>
> ```
> hashing.md5("Tag".utf8()) => b"wQEFjn6iG7vypayJMIjpCw=="
> ```

Comment: Thank you, Can I use hash in client site too ?? instead of crypto-js ?

Comment: i will be pleased if you show me like I need for example encrypting with hash256  in client side javascript and then decrypting that in security rules

Comment: You will have to find a library to do that. I can't make a recommendation. I'm sure a web search will help you.

Comment: So please only show me on security rules, example if my `uid` is hashed already, so will it work like this below: 
`hashing.sha256(request.auth.uid.utf8()) == userId`